# How to do a multiple image crossfading

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use "nth-of-type" but for some reason, only one image is playing and then they all disappear, then it goes back to the initial image. So not even the third image appears. I found this way in another post here, where it said that doing it this way is better than using "alternate" in each image but I don't know if this is right because it is not going in sequence. Only fades to the second image, then back to the initial one.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
0% {
  opacity:1;
}
45% {
opacity:1;
}
55% {
opacity:0;
}
100% {
opacity:0;
}
}

.App img {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;


-moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-duration: 8s;

-o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-duration: 8s;

animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 8s;
}



.App img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.App img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.App img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.App img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <img src="img/4.png" class="image4">
  <img src="img/3.png" class="image3">
  <img src="img/2.png" class="image2">
  <img src="img/1.png" class="image1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best is to set the opacity around  50% , here an example with also an increased duration :

```css
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 
  40%,
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.App {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

.App img {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

.App img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: -15s;
}

.App img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: -10s;
}

.App img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

.App img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200" class="image4">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/200" class="image3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/300/200" class="image2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/300/200" class="image1">
</div>
```

no need anymore of all those prefix BTW ;)

*A negative delay, sets right away on  the animation without waiting for the first loop to finish.*

**edit** Maybe a drawing to show why you need a different delay for each to dispatch animation on its timeline/duration :

```css
p {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 2em, lightgray 2em 4em);
  width: 20em;
}

b {
  display: block;
  background: white;
}

span {
  margin-left: var(--offSetLeft, 0);/* would be the delay moving it on the time line */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, blue 40% 60%, transparent);
  width: 20em;/* would be visually the duration */
}
```

```html
<p><b>Animation delay</b>
  <span style="--offSetLeft:-6em;">img 1</span>
  <span style="--offSetLeft:-2em;">img 2</span>
  <span style="--offSetLeft: 2em;">img 3</span>
  <span style="--offSetLeft: 6em;">img 4</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That helped! How do I set the same delay for all images? When I put the same time for all of them, it just goes to the second image and then goes back to the first..

Comment: you need to delay the animation if you 5 image an 10s, then a delay of 2 seconds will be needed, but will be very short, so you need also to increase the duration .  If you want a 2 second duration, with 5 image , it will be 5x2=10s with opacity set at 50% , you need to double the duration . Without delay, they will all fade in-out at the same time.

Comment: Vitor, I don't think you want the same delay for all images - you want one to start and run for a bit, then another to fade in and then another.

Comment: I don't know if I expressed myself correctly, but its basically this:

Image 1: Appears for 5 sec, 

Fades to image 2, 

Image 2: Appears for 5 sec, 

Fades to the next one..

Access Instagram website on 
an anonymous tab, they did it on the phone: https://instagram.com

Comment: as explained, if you want 5 seconds for each image, you need to increase the whole duration and multiplicate 5s x number of image x 2 (opacty:0 half of the time) , then delay each image animation from the previous . (my connexion is nuts)